# how can i have my timer for bubble sort and selection sort to work, it always shows zero

Tags: c++, sorting, timer, bubble-sort, selection-sort

my program works perfectly fine except i want it to display time it took to do the bubble sort and selection, I do have the code in the program but it always displays a 0. Please help.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct student { //structure student
unsigned int StuNo;
string LastName;
string FirstName;
double Gpa;
unsigned int Age;
string Major;
string College;

};

void clearCIN(void);
int inputInt(string, int, int);
double inputDouble(string, double, double);
string inputString(string, int, int);
// Note: changed "int" to "unsigned int", changed int to size_t
bool findstunum( unsigned int, vector<student>);
void initArrays (int[], double []);
char displayMenu(void);
void addstudent(vector<student> &);
void display(vector<student>);
void bubblesort(vector<student> &);
void selectionsort(vector<student> &);
void addrandomstudents(vector<student> &);
long double startTime;
long double endTime;



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

vector<student> myStudents; //Vector Student

srandom((unsigned int)time(NULL));
char userChoice;
bool keepdisplaying =true;

student tempstudent;

cout << "Welcome to our student management system\n========================================\n";
while (keepdisplaying) {      //displaying menu
    userChoice = displayMenu();
    switch (toupper(userChoice)) {

        case 'A':             //If user inputs 'A'
            addstudent(myStudents);
            break;
            //else

        case 'B':             //If user inputs 'B'
            bubblesort(myStudents);
            break;

        case 'S':             //If user inputs 'S'
            selectionsort(myStudents);
            break;

        case 'L':             //If user inputs 'l'
            display (myStudents);
            break;

        case 'X': keepdisplaying = false;  //if user wants to break.
            break;

        case 'R':
            addrandomstudents(myStudents);
            break;
    }
}

cout << endl << "Thank You for using our student management program\n";
cout << endl << "Have a great day!\n";
//
//End the program with an exit message
//
return 0;
} //main


//
//Clear the CIN input buffer to avoid problems
//
void clearCIN(void) {
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(32768, '\n');
return;
}   //clearCIN


//Input a integer value to be returned to the calling function.  Also, validate the
//the minimum and maximum value of the integer input.
//
int inputInt(string promptString, int minValue, int maxValue) {
int userInput;

cout << promptString << " \n";
while (true) {
    cin >> userInput;
    if (!cin.fail()) {
        char myChar = cin.peek();
        if (myChar == '\n')
            if (userInput >= minValue && userInput <= maxValue)
                break;
            else {
                cout << "Invalid value entered.  Should be between " << minValue << " and " <<        maxValue << " Please try again\n";
                clearCIN();
            }//else
            else {
                cout << "Invalid value entered.  Should be between " << minValue << " and " << maxValue << " Please try again\n";
                clearCIN();
            }//else
    }//if
    else {
        cout << "Invalid integer value entered. Please try again.\n";
        clearCIN();
    }//else
}
clearCIN();
return userInput;
}//inputInt

//
//Input a double value to be returned to the calling function.  Also, validate the
//the minimum and maximum value of the double input.
//
double inputDouble(string promptString, double minValue, double maxValue) {
double userInput;

cout << promptString << " \n";
while (true) {
    cin >> userInput;
    if (!cin.fail()) {
        char myChar = cin.peek();
        if (myChar == '\n')
            if (userInput >= minValue && userInput <= maxValue)
                break;
            else {
                cout << "Invalid value entered.  Should be between " << minValue << " and " <<         maxValue << " Please try again\n";
                clearCIN();
            }//else
            else {
                cout << "Invalid value entered.  Should be between " << minValue << " and " << maxValue << " Please try again\n";
                clearCIN();
            }//else
    }//if
    else {
        cout << "Invalid double value entered. Please try again.\n";
        clearCIN();
    }//else
}
clearCIN();
return userInput;
}//inputdouble

//
//Input a string to be returned to the calling function.
//
string inputString(string promptString, int minLength, int maxLength) {
string userInput;

while (true) {
    cout << promptString << "\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);
    if (userInput.size() < minLength || userInput.size() > maxLength) {
        cout << "The string you entered is too short or too long.  Should be " << minLength << "      to " << maxLength << " in Length\n";
        cout << "Please try again\n";
    }//if
    else
        break;
}//while
return userInput;
}//inputString


bool findstunum(unsigned int toFind, vector<student> numArray) {

for (size_t y=0; y<numArray.size(); y++) {
    if (numArray[y].StuNo == toFind)
        return true;
    else {}
}//for

return false;
}//findstudentnum
//
//Input a char for the menu
//
char displayMenu(void) {
char userSelection = ' ';   //The menu selection given by the user
bool keepAsking = true;     //While this is true, the while loop will continue to operate.

while (keepAsking) {
    cout << "Main Menu\n";
    cout << "---------\n";
    cout << "<A>dd a student\n";
    cout << "<L>ist students\n";
    cout << "<R>andomly generate 1000\n";
    cout << "<B>ubble sort by ID\n";
    cout << "<S>election sort by ID\n";
    cout << "e<X>it program\n";
    cin >> userSelection;

    switch (toupper(userSelection)) {
        case 'L':
        case 'l':
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'X':
        case 'x':
        case 'S':
        case 's':
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
        case 'R':
        case 'r':
            keepAsking = false; //Since the user has entered one of these, then we don't
            break;              //need to keep asking.
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Selection, please try again\n\n"; //Not sure this would ever     happen...
    }//switch
}//while
clearCIN(); //Always clear the CIN when a cin >> is done, just in case a getline will be       executed.
return userSelection;
}//displaymenu

void addrandomstudents(vector<student> &students) {
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    student tempstudent;
    tempstudent.Gpa   = (double)(random() % 100) / 25.0;

    bool duplicateFound = false;
    do {
        tempstudent.StuNo = random() % 1000;
        duplicateFound = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < students.size(); j++) {
            if(students[j].StuNo == tempstudent.StuNo) {
                duplicateFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(duplicateFound);
    tempstudent.FirstName = "joe"; //inputString("Enter the student's First name:", 1, 20);
    tempstudent.LastName = "Smith";// inputString("Enter the student's Last name:", 1, 20);
    tempstudent.Age   = 18;        // inputInt("Please Enter students age", 1, 100);
    tempstudent.Major = "Computer Science"; // inputString("Please Enter students major", 1,     1000);
    tempstudent.College = "UCSD";  // inputString("Please Enter students College", 1, 40);


    students.push_back(tempstudent);
    }

cout << "Thousand Students generated"  << endl;
}

void addstudent ( vector<student> &students){
cout << "New Student"  << endl;
student tempstudent;
bool keepGoing = true;
while (keepGoing) {


    tempstudent.StuNo = inputInt("Please enter student ID:", 1, 1000);

    // keepGoing = false; //out of while
    if (findstunum(tempstudent.StuNo, students))
        cout << "Student number already exists, please try again" << endl;
    else {

        keepGoing = false;
    }//else
}//while

tempstudent.Gpa   = inputDouble("Please enter the student's gpa", 0, 4);
tempstudent.FirstName = inputString("Enter the student's First name:", 1, 20);
tempstudent.LastName = inputString("Enter the student's Last name:", 1, 20);
tempstudent.Age   = inputInt("Please Enter students age", 4, 80);
tempstudent.Major = inputString("Please Enter students major", 1, 1000);
tempstudent.College = inputString("Please Enter students College", 1, 40);


students.push_back(tempstudent);

}

void display ( vector<student> students){
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "student Listing" << endl << endl;
cout << setw(10) << "Student ID" << setw(20) << "Student Name" << setw(16) << "Student GPA" <<   setw(15) << "Student Age" << setw(18) << "Student Major" << setw(25) << "Student College" << endl;
cout << setw(10) << "==========" << setw(20) << "============" << setw(16) << "===========" <<   setw(15) << "===========" << setw(18) << "=============" <<setw (25) << "===============" << endl;
for (int y=0; y< students.size(); y++) {
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(10) << students[y].StuNo << setw(20) <<   students[y].LastName + " " + students[y].FirstName << setw(16) << students[y].Gpa << setw(15)   <<students[y].Age << setw(18) << students[y].Major << setw(25) << students[y].College << endl;
}
}

//
//
//BUBBLE SORT
//
//

void bubblesort (vector<student> &students){
student tempStudent;
bool changed = true;

clock_t startingTime = clock();  //Timer begins

if (students.size() == 0){
    cout <<"Error, No students to sort!\n";
    return;              }

while (changed) {
    changed = false;
    for (int i=0; i<students.size()-1; i++) {
        if (students[i].StuNo >
            students[i+1].StuNo) {
            tempStudent = students[i];
            students[i] = students[i+1];
            students[i+1] = tempStudent;
            changed = true;
        }       //if
        else { }
    }//for
}

cout <<"Done Sorting!\n";

clock_t endTime = clock();  //Timer Ends
cout << "It took ";
cout << (endTime - startingTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << " seconds"<< endl;
}


//
//
//SELECTION SORT
//
//


void selectionsort(vector<student> &students)

{   student tempstudent;
int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

startScan = 0;
clock_t startingTime = clock();         //Timer for selection Sort begins

for(startScan = 0; startScan < students.size() - 1; startScan++)

{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = students[startScan].StuNo;
    for(int index = startScan + 1; index < students.size(); index++)
    {
        if (students[index].StuNo < minValue)
        {
            minValue = students[index].StuNo;
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }

    tempstudent = students[minIndex];
    students[minIndex] = students[startScan];
    students[startScan] = tempstudent;


}
cout <<"Done Sorting!\n";

clock_t endTime = clock();
cout << "It took ";
cout << (endTime - startingTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;   //Timer Ends
cout << " seconds"<< endl;
}
```

I have the code for timer above, it just shows 0 always, even when i change the program to display 10000 students instead of 1000. Also It doesn't actually need to display the seconds, it can simply display ticks, or something or that sort.

thanks

Comment: Give less code, please. Cut useless (to understand problem) functions. However, sorting of 10000 element is't so time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 - then use :

```html
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;

  time_t start = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());

  for (auto i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
  ;

  time_t difference = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now()) - start;

  std::cout << "Difference in seconds: " << difference;

  return 0;
}
```

For nanoseconds use the same system_clock::now() or other clocks if presented and std::chrono::nanosecods type. Conversion between time types is made using std::chrono::duration_cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write it like this:

```
cout << (endTime - startingTime) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
```

I think it takes you less than 1 second so if you have e.g. endTime - startingTime = 500 and divide it by 1000 result is 0.5 but since it is converted to int result is 0. (double) prevent conversion and show you 0.5 or something similar.

Comment: Would it still be in seconds?